# Redmine installation on 14.04

Tags: apache2, ruby, rails, redmine

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 server and want to install fresh Redmine. I faced several problems while installing, and still no LUCK. I found some documentations regarding installation but they are not helping me. I followed the tutorial on installation, which resulted redundant packages, configurations and my Ubuntu system is messy.

Now I am searching for easy Redmine installer (as .deb format or any script) which automatically installs or configures, so that I do not need to worry about configuration, installation of dependent packages. I have no idea about how ruby, rails,passenger works, really confusing. And again when I uninstall Redmine, should remove all related configurations or files.

Please help me guys. Will be grateful!

Comment: Can you provide the tutorial you followed?

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall     (official tutorial I guess)   https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step (This was easier, no luck)      https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_30x_on_Ubuntu_1404_with_Apache2_Phusion_Passenger_MySQL_Subversion_and_Git_(Gitolite)   ( I could not get out of it .. Did not know why git and subversion needs here )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing BitNami Redmine Stack**

Regardless of which operating system you are running (Windows / Linux / Mac), the install process is the same.

Download the latest version of Redmine Stack from the [BitNami website.](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine)

Find the installer you just downloaded (the filename will be similar to bitnami-Redmine-VERSION-linux-installer.run). Double click on the icon to launch the installer.

**Note: If you are using Linux you will have to give executable permissions to the file first, using this command in a terminal:**

```
chmod +x /path/to/bitnami-redmine-VERSION-linux-installer.run
```

[Reference](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/How_to_install_Redmine_in_Linux_Windows_and_OS_X_using_BitNami_Redmine_Stack)

Removing old packages or installs may depend on how you originally installed Redmine. You can try

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks @DnrDevil ! The installation worked without any problem. Its really great the installer automatically managed everything.

Comment: No problem please remember to close the question by clicking the ChecK MarK ;)